# Não recebe os dados do POST

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando gerar o login de acordo com os dados do banco de dados e prosseguir para a página restrita aos usuários registrados, mais decorre o erro de senha incorreta.

Front-end:

```
<div class="login-form">    
        <form action="modulo.php" method="POST">
        <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="email" >
        <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" value="password" >
        <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Login"> 
    </div>
```

Back-end

```
 <?php

    session_start();
    // error_reporting('1');
    include 'config.php';

    // username and password sent from form
    $myusername=$_POST['email'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['password'];


    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);


    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

    if($count==1){

    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "menu.php"
    $_SESSION['email']=$myusername;
    $_SESSION['password']=$mypassword;
    header("location:menu.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "<b class='error'>Wrong Username or Password</b>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Dá um print_r($_POST) no arquivo que recebe os dados e põe aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está a faltar `name="nomeDoCampo"` nos inputs da sua form...

Tente assim:

```
<div class="login-form">    
    <form action="modulo.php" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="email" >
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Senha" value="password" >
    <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Login"> 
</div>
```

Comment: tentei do modo que você informou, mais ainda não resolve o problema. :( ai vai uma imagem com o erro que está a ocorrer: http://i.imgur.com/laPvt9y.png

Comment: @theflash, teste isso no seu PHP: `var_dump($_POST);`, antes do SQL. Aparece o que escreveu no HTML?

Comment: @theflash O que acontece se você usar `$result=mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());`?

Comment: @Segio Tentei do modo sugerido mais está ocorrendo o erro: 
array(2) { ["email"]=> string(13) "test@test.com" ["password"]=> string(6) "123456" } No database selected

Comment: @bfavaretto apenas ocorre um erro.

Comment: @theflash, ok, essa respsta diz-me que o erro está do lado do servidor. Proxima pergunta: se fôr ver o registo na base de dados a password está escondida (ecriptada com md5) ou dá para ler a palavra?

Comment: @Sergio A senha está em varchar, não está criptografada.

Comment: @theflash já conseguiu pôr a funcionar? Se não teste esta string no SQL: `"SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='".$myusername."' and password='".$mypassword."'"`

Comment: @Sergio está a decorrer o erro:  No database selected

Comment: @theflash adicione esta linha no inicio do seu PHP e diga se aparece algum erro. Acho que o config.php não está a ser lido...: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: O erro que você postou acima diz "No database selected". Ou seja, faltou usar `mysql_select_db` no config.php.

Comment: Realmente era isto @bfavaretto obrigado. Obrigado também Sergio.

Comment: @theflash, ótimo. Eu queria chegar aí mas dei passos mais curtos, queria ter a certeza que o `config.php` estava a carregar.

Comment: Problema resolvido. ;)

Answer (score 1):

O problema é a função `mysql_*` que voce esta usando.

Ela já esta obsoleta e muito vuneravél. use a biblioteca mysqli_* ou aprenda PDO.

No caso, o seu código ficará assim.

```
$myusername=mysqli_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$mypassword=mysqli_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['password']));
```

Esta dando erro no mysql_num_rows, porque como essa função mysql_real_escape_string o EasyPHP não esta processando, ai ele não atribui nada para sua váriavel, passando nenhum valor para o SQL.

OBS: Como voce utilizando a biblioteca mysqli_* no exemplo acima, terá que adaptar todo seu código com essa lib, no caso a maioria das funções, coloca o "i" no final.

Comment: Ok. irei estudar alguns experimentos com mysqli e pdo.

Comment: Problema ao menos foi resolvido?

Comment: Sim, questão já solucionada.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
<?php

session_start();
// error_reporting('1');
include 'config.php';

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['password']));


$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "menu.php"
$_SESSION['email']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['password']=$mypassword;
header("location:menu.php");
}
else {
echo "<b class='error'>Wrong Username or Password</b>";
}
?>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta mais o erro ainda persiste.